# Computing the degeneracy of a graph?

Tags: python, graph

I'm looking for a way to compute the degeneracy of a given graph. The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_%28graph_theory%29) outlines a way, but it also stores the degeneracy ordering and I think I've seen a simpler algorithm somewhere online weeks ago but I can't find it now. I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to compute the degeneracy of a graph if I have no interest in storing the degeneracy ordering of the graph?

I am using networkx and Python if it matters at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetworkX has Batagelj and Zaversnik's O(m) core algorithm which I think you can use for your purpose:
`degeneracy(G) = max(networkx.core_number(G).values())`?
http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/algorithms.core.html